# Proxy didn't change in request

Tags: python, proxy, request, python-requests

**Hello i wanted to requests.get some api, but every request will change proxy**

This is way i tried, but everytime it request from mine ip and it wont use proxies

```
p = open(f"proxies.txt", encoding="UTF-8")
proxylist = p.read().split('\n')

while amount > 0:
    rproxy = random.choice(proxylist)
    proxies = {
        "http": rproxy
    }
    amount = amount - 1
    url = requests.get(f"https://httpbin.org/ip", proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: You doesn't avoid duplicates, btw.

Comment: Probably your proxies are not 100% private and are sending your information to the destination url!